# How to Change the property of an Observable Object. Angular 2/BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an object of type Person which has fields of firstName, lastName, age. I detect for any change using Behavior Subject. I have an observing component that is subscribed to every change on this Person Object. Once the change detects the observing component will call a method. I want this method to change the property of the Observable Person Object.

In My Service

```
export class PersonService {

    personToCopySource = new BehaviorSubject<Person>(null);
    personToCopy = this.personToCopySource.asObservable();
```

In My Component

```
 export class ObservingComponent {

    constructor(public person: Person) {}

    ngOnInit(){
      this.personService.person.subscribe(
         data=> {
           this.updateMethod()
          }
      )
    }

   updateMethod(){
     this.personService.firstName = 'updated First Name';
   }
```

When I change the property of the Observing object I'm getting this error. "Property" firstName does not exist on type Observable

Comment: An observable is a stream. It does not have properties. What do you want to do? Do you want to put your own value on the stream? In that case, you could try `Subject#next`.

Comment: Originally I have a variable person of type Person inside a service. What I want is to detect for any change in the property of this object. Is there other way to detect the change of variable declared inside a service.?

Answer (score 2):

An observable is a stream. It does not have properties. What do you want to do? Do you want to put your own value on the stream, with `firstName` updated? In that case, you could try `Subject#next`.

```
export class PersonService {

  personToCopySource = new BehaviorSubject<Person>(null);
  personToCopy = this.personToCopySource.asObservable();

  // Provide a method to update a person,
  // by putting a new or updated person on the stream.
  update(person: Person) { 
    this.personToCopySource.next(person); 
  }
```

In My Component

```
export class ObservingComponent {

    constructor(public person: Person) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.personService.personToCopy.subscribe(
            data=> {
                this.updateMethod(data)
            })
    }

    updateMethod(data){
        this.personService.update({...data, firstName: 'updated First Name'});
    }
```

Comment: I have a question in updated method inside the service.Will updating the person crteates a new person object and replace the previous person Or is it the same person Object and just updating the firtsName property?

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ You need to understand the concept of streams. A stream is a sequence of things. They just come, one by one. You don't change them. You read things off the stream with `subscribe`, or can place new things on a stream with `next()`. Placing a new item on the stream is not "replacing" anything: it's just placing a new item on the stream. A new item on the stream may be a modified version of the previous item, but that does not mean it "updates" the previous item, which has probably already been processed in its original state.

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ, how to update "this.personService" object to null?

In my case, after a button click i need to reset the values. Do you have any idea?